# Place SL below the low of entry trigger Inside Candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I have a Inside Candle strategy.
According to code I have written I get stopped out below the low of coming Inside Candle.

Please Help !

exact problem image =>(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTiXP.png)

I want to exit at the low of entry trigger Inside Candle.
How Can I Do it?

Code is as follows :

```
//@version=5
strategy("Inside Candle Bar", overlay=true,process_orders_on_close=true)

//================================================Money Management==========================================================================================


//=============================================Entry and exit Timings (9:30 a.m. to 2:30 p.m.)===========================================================

string sessionInput = input.session("0930-1415", "Session")
string daysInput = input.string("1234567", tooltip = "1 = Sunday, 7 = Saturday")
sessionString = sessionInput + ":" + daysInput
inSession = not na(time(timeframe.period, sessionString))
bgcolor(inSession ? color.rgb(178, 181, 190, 96) : na)

//================================================Detecting Inside Candle,ema,high,low====================================================================

//Defining Inside Candle and 50ema

ema = ta.ema(close,50)
IC = (high <= high[1] and low >= low[1])

//Detecting Inside Candle High and Low

h = high[0] + (2 * syminfo.mintick)
l = low[0] - (2* syminfo.mintick)

//==================================================Defining Entry Conditions=====================================================================================================

//LONG above 50ema and SHORT below 50ema

ICwithEMALONG = IC and (close > ema)
ICwithEMASHORT = IC and (close < ema)

//Previous Candle is an Inside Candle = IC[1] and // High of current candle is greater than previous (Inside) candle = high > high[1] 
//and close of previous(Inside) candle > ema = close[1] > ema then ====>>>>>> LONG

EntryCandleLONG = IC[1] and (high[0] > high[1]) and (close[1] > ema)
EntryCandleSHORT = IC[1] and (low[0] < low[1]) and (close[1] < ema) 

//==================================================================//PlottingEMa===================================================================

plot(ema,"EMA",color.blue,linewidth = 2)

//======================================================================Coloring Bars===========================================

barcolor(ICwithEMALONG ? color.white : na)
barcolor(ICwithEMASHORT ? color.white : na)
barcolor(EntryCandleLONG ? color.yellow : na)
barcolor(EntryCandleSHORT ? color.yellow : na)

//==============================================LONG Entry and Exit Conditions==========================================================================

if (ICwithEMALONG and inSession) 
    strategy.entry("LONG",strategy.long,stop =  h)

    stoploss = l
    target = h + ((h-l)*3)

    
   strategy.exit("LONGExit",from_entry="LONG",stop=stoploss,limit=target)
```

Comment: How can we help without seeing your code?

Comment: I have provided full code.

Answer (score 0):

In your strategy declaration, you have :

process_orders_on_close=true

This prevent you to open or exit order during a formation of the candle.
I think you should delete this on your strategy declaration to get the result your are looking for.